# listview is not showing the data in another page using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

i am newly working for jquery mobile panels, i have tried the reference of this jsfiddle link here http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vds2U/47/ , i just added jquery ajax call to parse xml data. My problem is after searching city and keyword in page1, ajax call shows success alert but not trigger to page2. I want to display data in page2. If i click on page2 in jquery panel it appends the searched data. What wrongs here If any changes need to do please help me. My code is like below:

html code:

```
<div data-role="panel" data-display="push" data-theme="b" id="nav-panel" data-position="left">
<h2> All Pages </h2>
<ul data-role="listview"  data-icon="false">
<li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#panel-main">Main panel page</a></li>                
<li><a href="#page1">page 1 page</a></li>
<li><a href="#page2">page 2 Page</a></li>
</ul>
</div> 


<div data-role="page" id="panel-main" data-title="Panel main"  data-theme="a" >
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<h1 id="header1">main panel</h1>
<a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
</div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content"">
<p id="para1">main panel</p>
</div>            
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<h1>page 1</h1>
<a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
</div>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<div class="text"><input type="text" id="p1" name="p1" placeholder="Location...." class="user-text1 textboxes" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true" />
</div>
<div class="height"></div>
<div class="text"><input type="text" id="p2" name="p2" placeholder="Term...." class="user-text2 textboxes" data-clear-btn="true" /></div>
<div class="height"></div>

<button type="submit" id="searchBtn" data-theme="f" data-corners="false"/>Search Events</button>
</div>
</div> 

<div data-role="page" id="page2"  data-theme="a" >
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<h1>page 2</h1>
<a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
</div>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-icon="false" data-autodividers="true" data-theme="c"></ul>
</div>
</div>  
<script>
$(function () {
$("[data-role=panel]").enhanceWithin().panel();
});
```

javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#searchBtn").bind("click",function(){
// alert('success');
$.mobile.loading('show');
var p1=$("#p1").val();
var p2=$("#p2").val();
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url:"http://api2.yp.com/listings/v1/search?searchloc="+p1+"&term="+p2+&format=xml&key=5cbqjx3cdl",

dataType: "xml",
success: function(data){
//alert('success');    
$(data).find("searchListing").each(function(){        
var name=$(this).find("businessName").text();
var  id=$(this).find("listingId").text();                   
window.location.href="#page2";
//$.mobile.changePage("#page2");       
$.mobile.loading('hide');           
$("#list").append('<li>name:'+ name +'</li>');
$("#list:visible").listview("refresh");

});//ajax ends


});


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jQM pagecreate instead of $(document).ready, then in the success function, append the new items to the list, navigate to page2 using pagecontainer("change"), then refresh the list:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    $("#searchBtn").on("click" ,function(){

      // your AJAX code

      success: function(data){
        //alert('success');    
        $(data).find("searchListing").each(function(){        
        var name=$(this).find("businessName").text();
        var  id=$(this).find("listingId").text();                   
        $.mobile.loading('hide');           
        $("#list").append('<li>name:'+ name +'</li>');
        $("body").pagecontainer( "change", "#page2", {} );
        $("#list").listview("refresh");

    });
  });
});
```

> Simplified **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9prtq/)**

I have left the AJAX out of the demo. I am just appending 3 items and then changing page.

Comment: Hi Sorry for the late reply. Still i am not getting the dynamic output to page2 using ajax call. I was changing like above lines of code and run the App usually. output is not shown. Please help me. Any alternate solution actually i was using slidebars plugin for them also same issue for page2 list output. So i preffered for jquery mobile panels.

Comment: Is the XML data actually being returned in the success function? Does $(this).find("businessName").text() return a value?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir. Yes, its Xml data returned in the success function, in my previous code i am getting the list output but not triggering the page2 thats the issue. I want jquery mobile panels for each page, actually i am developing sample program for phonegap android app so page1 for searching, page2 for list output finally page3 for detailed description of each list, this is what i am trying. Please guide me is there any other solution.

Comment: Are you using version 1.4.2 of jQM? My demo jsFiddle both fills the list and changes page, are you sure you are doing things in the same order?

Comment: Yes using jQM 1.4.2 Version and tried the same order. Ajax loader is continuously running but not shows the output or trigger to page2.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a jsFiddle? Otherwise it is hard to say what the problem is...

Comment: Are you sure the id="list" is a unique id across all pages?

Comment: Hi Sir, i have fed up with small issue the above solution, after click on search button in page1 its successfully redirects to page2 and shows the list output. If i click on page1 in a panel its automatically goes to page2. How i can stop this? any solution...